# How to make live streaming tv with node multiple clients

Tags: node.js, firebase, video-streaming, live-streaming, video-on-demand

Need a solution to play(broadcast) video using node.

My requirement is to start broadcasting a video when event starts, the person visits page from middle then he can watch only from middle of the video.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a nice idea for an app. It's a bit unclear what you're asking however. If the question is on how to get started, I'd recommend picking any of the technologies involved and reading more about that.

Comment: No need for Node, you can do all of this client-side by seeking to the correct position in the video.  Don't make this more complicated than it needs to be, and you'll be able to leverage normal static CDNs.